# I have some problems installing ckeditor, anyone who might be able to assist me?

Tags: ckeditor, editor, textarea

Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/bL9pacC7

I have been trying to replace the textarea normal textbox to a CKEditor, is there anyone who can assist me with that? i'm pretty new at this so i will in advance say i'm sorry about my noobness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the "replace by class" method, you should assign the `ckeditor` class directly to the `<textarea>` element that you want to replace with CKEditor, so try:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="pagecontent" id="pagecontent" cols="50" rows="5">
   <?php echo($pagecontent) ?>
</textarea>
```

See an example (albeit without PHP) here: http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/replacebyclass.html

Comment: BTW. I don't know where the `$pagecontent` comes from, but usually before printing the content out to a `textarea` it has to be encoded with `htmlspecialchars()`.